# Trying to get a Core Data record by ObjectID returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When I'm saving a new record into my database, I'm getting its permanent ObjectID and save it as a string in `UserDefaults`. My `save` method looks like:

```
func save(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
    if validate() {
        coreDataStack.saveContext(managedObjectContext)

        let isSaved = user.objectID.isTemporaryID
        completion(isSaved)

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.obtainPermanentIDs(for: [user])
            UserDefaults.standard.set(user.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString, forKey: Constansts.shared.kCurrentUser)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not obtain permanent ID for the user. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        completion(false)
    }
}
```

and later I'm trying to get that record by ObjectID as:

```
let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack(modelName: "MyDB")

        do {
            if let currentUser = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constansts.shared.kCurrentUser), let objectURL = URL(string: currentUser) {
                let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: coreDataStack.storeContainer.managedObjectModel)
                if let objectID = coordinator.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: objectURL) {
                    let user = try coreDataStack.mainContext.existingObject(with: objectID) as! Users

                    let viewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
                    viewController.viewModel = NewPlanViewModel(for: user, with: coreDataStack, and: coreDataStack.mainContext)
                }
            } else {
                fatalError("Could not find the user to create a new plan for him.")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not get current user. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

And hier as a result I'm getting `nil`. At first I thought that it is because of `permanentID` and `temporalID` but after using `try managedObjectContext.obtainPermanentIDs(for: [user])` I'm getting the same `nil`.

Can someone help me to improve my code?